# Remote upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.4 LTS stopped - How to resume?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, ssh, do-release-upgrade

I'm doing a remote upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.4 LTS over ssh, trying to follow this recipe:
https://ostechnix.com/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-lts-server/

However, it seems the upgrade stopped while cleaning up the packages -- it detached from screen and never got to the "System upgrade complete" message. Running `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` again says "There is no development version of an LTS available". Since this is remote, I'm afraid to reboot or do the wrong thing. How can I check/resume/fix the upgrade?

Here's the last part of the /var/log/dist-upgrade/.../main.log:

```
2020-09-26 10:20:41,799 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", 
line 997, in tryMarkObsoleteForRemoval
    self.restore_snapshot()

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", 
line 370, in restore_snapshot
    pkg.mark_delete()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1509, in mark_delete

apt_pkg.Error: E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/focal", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 238, in main
    if app.run():

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2081, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 2058, in fullUpgrade
    self.doPostUpgrade()

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1484, in doPostUpgrade
    if not self.cache.tryMarkObsoleteForRemoval(pkgname, remove_candidates, self.forced_obsoletes, self.foreign_pkgs):

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 243, in wrapper
    res = f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 1001, in tryMarkObsoleteForRemoval
    self.restore_snapshot()

  File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-soxxvnbe/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeCache.py", line 370, in restore_snapshot
    pkg.mark_delete()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 1509, in mark_delete

apt_pkg.Error: E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```